# JTable object array

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable

```
String[] columnNames = {"Type", "Employee ID", "First/Last Name","DOB", "Gender", "HIre Date", "OnCall", "BaseSalary", "Commission/Hourly Rate"};
    Object[][] data = new Object[10][9];
table = new JTable(data,columnNames);

public ArrayList<Person> employeeList = new ArrayList<Person>();
public ArrayList<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
public ArrayList<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList<Stock>();
```

I'm trying to create a JTable with information inside a array-list. I tried something along the lines of.

```
data[0][0] = "Account";
data[0][1] = 1; //int
data[0][2] = "Name";
data[0][3] = dob; //Date class
data[0][4] = gender; //Enum 
data[0][5] = hire //Date class
data[0][6] = true; //boolean
data[0][7] = 125.23; //double
data[0][8] =  0.015; //double
```

Which didn't work out really well, I try google but most of the examples have pre-made arrays so didn't help much.

Comment: It's unclear why it did not work, what were you expecting and what happened instead?

Comment: I was actually expecting it to work but apparently it didn't since the code I'm working with the person before had a exception handling and threw a error

Comment: Strangely enough now I create the table accept none of the data is going in at all...

Comment: Are you putting the objects in data before the JTable creation?

Comment: Yea, which I think might be the issue, I ended up just making a empty table, and just adding rows which seem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the data array. Arrays in java are not dynamic. Defining

`Object[][] data = {};`

you are creating an array of length 0.

You'd have to be able to know their lengths beforehand and [use them in the creation](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/170/notes/2dArrays/ar2.html) or use the List's [toArray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) method.

Comment: could I specify the size such as Object[row][col] data;

Comment: No. `Object[][] data = new Object[rows][cols];`

Answer (score 1):

The JTable model documentation is confusingly in it's simplistic explanations. It's almost always a mistake to pass in data to the table constructor. You should implement your own table model that is derived form AbstractTableModel, and pass that model object into the constructor for the table.

Then your table model, can just have a private member variable like

```
public ArrayList<Person> employeeList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

then you just need to implement a few methods, like

```
public int getRowCount() {
    return emplyeeList.size();
}
```

and such as

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Person p = employeeList.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 1: 
              return p.getName();
        ....
    }
}
```

etc.

It makes your programming much simpler as the model uses your natural data structures to hold the data.